# Array defaulting to 'nothing' rather than '0' in Structure

Tags: vb.net, arrays, structure

I'm currently stuck on an issue regarding declaring an array of type short in a structure and having it default to 'nothing' rather than '0' after ReDim.

```
'Declaring array and setting it's initial size


Private Structure Totals_T  
Dim sTot_Desc As String 
<VBFixedArray(10)> Dim iTot_Cnt() As Short  
        Public Sub Initialize()  
                ReDim iTot_Cnt(10)  
End Sub 

End Structure   

Private m_Totals() As Totals_T 'Define the array 


'Calling the structure for the two variables declared in the structure
 If iNewCnt = 1 Then 
 ReDim m_Totals(10)  
 **m_Totals(0).**iTot_Cnt(iColumn_No) = m_Totals(0).iTot_Cnt(iColumn_No) + 1
```

When calling m_Totals(0) the arrays returned have 10 records in the arry with sTot_Desc and iTot_Cnt having values of nothing in all records.

When I ReDim m_Totals both the variables I declared in the structure(sTot_Desc and iTot_Cnt) are declared as nothing, it's fine for the String but I need the Short I declared to be declared as '0', which is what I thought happens when you ReDim. Can anyone see what's going on here and why it's declaring my variables as 'nothing' rather than defaulting to '0' for the short and ""/nothing for the string?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is that you are not calling the Initialize method after ReDimming the structure array. You can fix this like:

```
   For Each total As Totals_T In m_Totals
        total.Initialize()
    Next
```

The second issue is that strings are always initialized to nothing; you need to explicitly set them to empty string if you want anything to happen. You can fix this by changing the Initialize method:

```
    Public Sub Initialize()
        sTot_Desc = String.Empty
        ReDim iTot_Cnt(10)
    End Sub
```